# PLSQL apresenta erro erro: PLS-00103 em função ao utilizar um Exception

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

O PLSQL está informando o erro PLS-00103 quando eu tento compilar esta função.
Observação: Caso eu tente executar apenas com a primeira opção deste case "P_TIP = 1" ele executa normalmente.
Caso eu tente adicionar o case "P_TIP = 2" ele simplesmente retorna este erro.

Reitero que os dois Selects dentro dos cases estão funcionando perfeitamente no banco, eu apenas copiei eles para a função inserindo o INTO P_VALOR.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FC_PERS_RAIOX (P_ANO INT, P_CODPARCMATRIZ INT, P_TIP INT)
RETURN FLOAT
IS
   P_VALOR FLOAT;
BEGIN

    BEGIN
        -- BUSCA A VENDA ACUMULADA PARA O CLIENTE
    CASE WHEN P_TIP = 1 THEN

         SELECT
         SUM(MRG.VLRTOT) INTO P_VALOR
         FROM AD_DADOSMRG_EX MRG
         WHERE
         MRG.DTENTSAI BETWEEN '01/01/'||P_ANO AND '31/12/'||P_ANO AND
         MRG.TIPMOV IN ('V', 'D') AND
         MRG.GRUPO IN ('VENDAS') AND
         MRG.CODPARCMATRIZ = P_CODPARCMATRIZ
         GROUP BY 1;
         -- BUSCA DESCONTO MEDIO DO CLIENTE
    CASE WHEN P_TIP = 2 THEN
         
         SELECT
         ROUND((1-(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), P_ANO, MRG.VLRTOT,0))/SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), P_ANO, MRG.PRTAB,0))))*100,2) INTO P_VALOR
         FROM AD_DADOSMRG_EX MRG
         WHERE
         MRG.TIPMOV IN ('V', 'D') AND
         MRG.GRUPO IN ('VENDAS') AND
         MRG.CODPARCMATRIZ = P_CODPARCMATRIZ
         GROUP BY 1;
         END CASE;
              
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

        P_VALOR := 0;
    END;

    RETURN P_VALOR;

END;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

descobri o problema.

Eu estava criando dois CASES.

NA LINHA ONDE ESTÁ ESCRITO: CASE WHEN P_TIP = 2 THEN
O CORRETO SERIA SOMENTE: WHEN P_TIP = 2 THEN